# How to compile C++ code with iostream include

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to compile a small piece of C++ code with Visual Studio 2015,and when I include iostream library,I get some weird compile errors,Can anyone help me solve it ?

Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Somethig" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the errors I get when I compile this

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  ConsoleApplication3.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(100): error C2737: 'std::is_same_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(100): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_same_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(245): error C2737: 'std::is_integral_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(245): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_integral_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(282): error C2737: 'std::is_floating_point_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(282): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_floating_point_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(295): error C2737: 'std::is_arithmetic_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(295): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_arithmetic_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstddef(697): error C2737: 'std::is_function_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstddef(697): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_function_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(524): error C2275: '_To': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(521): note: see declaration of '_To'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(526): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_assignable<_To,_From>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(524): error C2275: '_From': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(522): note: see declaration of '_From'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(524): error C3861: '__is_assignable': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(524): error C2975: '_Val': invalid template argument for 'std::integral_constant', expected compile-time constant expression
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(21): note: see declaration of '_Val'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1245): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__make_integer_seq'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1249): error C2065: '_Vals': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1249): error C2975: '_Vals': invalid template argument for 'std::integer_sequence', expected compile-time constant expression
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1190): note: see declaration of '_Vals'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1252): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'make_integer_sequence'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1261): error C2631: 'identity': a class or enum cannot be defined in an alias template
1>c:\users\ugurku\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\stdafx.cpp : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
1>  INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe'
1>      Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>      Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

All helps will be appriciated.

Comment: Get rid of `#include "stdafx.h"`.

Comment: An ICE is always a compiler bug. Something's wrong with your installation. How did you install VS2015?

Comment: The usual way,installed it with visual studio installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a problem about my Visual Studio installation,I just reinstalled it and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

```html
#include <cstdlib>
```

You should reinstall the visual studios because the only thing I think of why you code wouldn't compile would be is because you forget the library header

Comment: I did,same code compiles when I reinstalled the studio

Comment: @Uğur KURT-Have you tried downloading MinGW C++ compiler for windows 10? I have that currently. Let know if you decide to do that. Any time one software doesn't work for you, you can always try something else.